# How to Scan QR Code on Screen like WhatsApp

Tags: qr-code, whatsapp, barcode-scanner

I am looking for QR scan feature like WhatsApp. In WhatsApp when you open any QR image it automatically scan it. Please see the attached screenshot for the same.

[image]

How WhatsApp is doing what mechanism behind this.

Can you please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Barcode scanner library for Android, based on the ZXing decoder try this one.

[QR Code Reader GitHub Library](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded)

Comment: This is not a on screen scanner as I mentioned in question.